# How to fix error in Fortran program reading a .dat file?

Tags: fortran

I have to write a Fortran program for a homework assignment. When I compile it, I get this :

```
At line 36 of file projetfinal2.f90 (Unit 10 "PARAM.dat")
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input
```

I don't understand this error, can you help me fix this please?

''' this is the part of the program that uses the .dat file'''

```
SUBROUTINE initialisation(r,l_clear,f,it_max,densite)                   
        TYPE(ROUTE),INTENT(INOUT) :: r
        REAL,INTENT(OUT) :: f

        INTEGER,INTENT(OUT):: it_max
        LOGICAL,INTENT(OUT) :: l_clear
        INTEGER::ios                                        
        OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='PARAM.dat',FORM='formatted',ACTION='read',iostat=ios)
        IF (ios/=0) STOP 'Erreur'


        READ (UNIT=10,FMT=*) r%n_max                        
        READ (UNIT=10,FMT=*) r%v_max                

        READ (UNIT=10,FMT=*) f  
        READ (UNIT=10,FMT=*) it_max 
        READ (UNIT=10,FMT=*) l_clear                



        CLOSE(UNIT=10)
        END SUBROUTINE initialisation
```

'''this is the .dat file'''

```
        60
        3
        1
        0.3
        30
        .TRUE.
```

Comment: Is it trying to read 0.3 into integer it_max?

Comment: Welcome, please take the welcome [tour] to find out how this site works.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I've found the mistake, as you said Mark Plotnick I had forgotten the read line assigned to 0.3. Next time I'll take your advice High Performance Mark. Thanks again